# How can I plot a time series that shows only days on x-axis?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I want to draw this time series plot using R.

[image: Line plot]

My dataset is a time series that includes days, hours and minutes. I want the plot to show only the day of the week. When I use a normal `plot(x,y)` i get a `box plot` and I am not able to figure out the type of this plot. Can anyone help me in figuring out the plot and which function can be used to get such a plot.

Head of actual data:

```
head(data)
#        Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage
#1 2006-12-16 17:24:00               4.216                 0.418  234.84
#2 2006-12-16 17:25:00               5.360                 0.436  233.63
#3 2006-12-16 17:26:00               5.374                 0.498  233.29
#4 2006-12-16 17:27:00               5.388                 0.502  233.74
#5 2006-12-16 17:28:00               3.666                 0.528  235.68
#6 2006-12-16 17:29:00               3.520                 0.522  235.02

#  Global_intensity Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
#1             18.4              0              1             17
#2             23.0              0              1             16
#3             23.0              0              2             17
#4             23.0              0              1             17
#5             15.8              0              1             17
#6             15.0              0              2             17
```

Minimally reproducible dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(rep(c("2006-06-16", "2006-06-17"), each = 1440)),
  Time = format(as.difftime(0:1439, units = "mins") + as.POSIXct("2006-06-16"), "%H:%M"),
  Global_active_power = cumsum(rnorm(2880, 0.02, 0.02) * rep(rep(c(1, -1), 4), 2880 / 8)))
```

At this stage, I've tried the following:

```
x <- weekdays(data$Date)
y <- data$Global_active_power

plot(x, y)
```

but I get a boxplot.

Comment: make sure that your `x` variable didn't get turned into a factor by accident.  Give us `summary(x)` and `summary(y)`.

Comment: `plot` is a generic function and depending on the data you pass in, a boxplot, time series plot, ... is created. In other words: What you get depends on the data you pass in. Therefore: Please add `dput(x);dput(y)` to your question.

Comment: We don't have your data and we don't read minds. For starters you could try `type = "l"`, but I'm guessing there is a reason why you are getting a box plot as default.

Comment: `x` consists of "Thursday" and "Friday". How were you expecting that to translate into a line graph?

Comment: I want my y to plot against different days of a week. I have a column date I got the day by using weekdays function and added it to the data set as x and I want to plot a graph between x and y

Comment: @Mini but at this stage you have 1440 data points with the same x. Do you have times or something else?

Comment: Yes. I have date and time in my columns and I used only weekdate(data$date) to get the week day. Should I do it in any other way? Please suggest me. I have edited my question and given you the head of the dataset. Please suggest me how to get that graph.

Comment: You don't know the order of the `x` values, so how do we know what order it should be in! If you want to reproduce the graph you have above, you could do something like this: `plot(y, type='l', xaxt='n') ; axis(1, at=c(1, 1268), labels=c("Friday", "Thursday"))`

Comment: It sounds like you do not want to do the day you want to do the time and subset your data so that you only have the two days of the week that you want.  I would first do the subset then plot the x as a time. When you get it working you can put labels on that show which times are on Thursday and which on Friday.

Comment: @chappers...how did you put the values of at=c(1,1268) ? what is 1268 here?

Comment: I've reworded the question to explain what I think the OP was requesting. If it gets reopened, I'll post this as an answer: At present, you're converting the date to a character vector with the weekday. `plot` assumes you want to compare the value of `y` for the two values of `x` and so produces a boxplot. What you actually need to do is to plot `y` against the date/time as a `POSIXct` value. This can be done as follows: `data$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(data$Date), data$Time)); plot(Global_active_power ~ DateTime, data, type = "l")`

Comment: Is my answer what you wanted? If so you should mark it correct. If not you should post the correct answer, or indicate what is still bothering you. Otherwise it stays open and unanswered forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(rep(c("2006-06-16", "2006-06-17"), each = 1440)),
                   Time = format(as.difftime(0:1439, units = "mins") + 
                                 as.POSIXct("2006-06-16"), "%H:%M"),
                   Global_active_power = cumsum(rnorm(2880, 0.02, 0.02) *
                                         rep(rep(c(1, -1), 4), 2880 / 8)))

data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date,data$Time),tz="UCT")
plot(data$datetime,data$Global_active_power,type="l")
```

Here is the plot:
[image]